# What is it and where can I find or take those holopics?

Tags: gamedec

During the Knight's Code mission, there is a faulty NPC that you have to fix or kill.

If you try to expose her, she will give you a job.

You have to collect those two holopics.

I have searched the entire map and couldn't find it.

How do I take those holopics?

[image: quest log]

> Search the Clan's Stronghold
>
> - [0/2] **Take holopics for the "faulty
>   enpec"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found both of them inside Umbra's chamber:

[image]

[image]